# How do I set these break points in ~/.gdbinit?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, memory-management, gdb

Here is a list of break points to put in ~/.gdbinit that are really helpful in debugging memory problems:

```
fb -[NSException raise]
fb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:]
fb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]

#define NSZombies
# this will give you help messages.  Set to NO to turn them off.
set env MallocHelp=YES
# might also be set in launch arguments.
set env NSZombieEnabled=YES
set env NSDeallocateZombies=NO
set env MallocCheckHeapEach=100000
set env MallocCheckHeapStart=100000
set env MallocScribble=YES
set env MallocGuardEdges=YES
set env MallocCheckHeapAbort=1

set env CFZombie 5

fb -[_NSZombie init]
fb -[_NSZombie retainCount]
fb -[_NSZombie retain]
fb -[_NSZombie release]
fb -[_NSZombie autorelease]
fb -[_NSZombie methodSignatureForSelector:]
fb -[_NSZombie respondsToSelector:]
fb -[_NSZombie forwardInvocation:]
fb -[_NSZombie class]
fb -[_NSZombie dealloc]

fb szone_error
```

Comment: These may indeed be helpful, but is there a question as part of this? SO is not a wiki for posting helpful tips — those belong on http://www.cocoadev.com, at least for Objective-C and Cocoa.

Comment: @Quinn: it can be, but according to the FAQ it should be posted as a question which you can then answer yourself ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of this indicates that you are asking how to set these in ~/.gdbinit but the first line of your detailed question indicates that you have the above in ~/.gdbinit?

What, exactly, is the problem, then?

I use something pretty similar and it works fine, but since much of this is fairly intrusive behavioral changes, I put it in a separate file (~/.gdbmem) and then source it as needed.

My ~/.gdbinit is limited almost entirely to macro definitions that don't otherwise change the debugging session.   Thus, the default behavior is minimal impact on debugging and I can source one of 2 additional files full of gdb config goop to automatically apply some relatively intrusive additional configuration to the environment.

Comment: It isn't in Xcode;  .gdbinit is a file you can drop in your home directory that gdb will parse when gdb launches, either from the command line or from within Xcode.

Comment: could you please make it more clear...how do i create .gdbinit file and how do parse this from xcode

Comment: You create a new file called .gdbinit - put it in your home directory.

Now every time gdb starts it will execute the commands in this file.