# Shouldn't Xcode/gdb load the ~/.gdbinit file on launch?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gdb, breakpoints

I have a ~/.gdbinit file which is loosely based on [How do I set these break points in ~/.gdbinit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237830/how-do-i-set-these-break-points-in-gdbinit).  Allegedly, gdb is supposed to source ~/.gdbinit when it launches.  However, it's not loading mine - I have to stop at an existing breakpoint and type in 'source ~/.gdbinit', and then it loads it.  Is there a way to have gdb or Xcode do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode possibly invokes gdb as `gdb -nx ...`.

There probably is some setting somewhere in Xcode to change that.